# Postgres: Querying whole rows in a many to many relationship

Tags: postgresql, many-to-many, supabase

My table is currently structured as follows:

```
PATHS TABLE

UID uuid primary | NAME text | DURATION number
<uuid 0>         | Path 1    | 60



STOPS TABLE

UID uuid primary | NAME text | ADDRESS text
<uuid 1>         | Stop 1    | Whatever Str.
<uuid 2>         | Stop 2    | Whatever2 Str.



PATH_STOP TABLE

id int primary | PATH uuid fk | STOP uuid fk
0              | <uuid 0>     | <uuid 1>
1              | <uuid 0>     | <uuid 2>
```

Meaning that each path has multiple stops assigned to it and one stop can be possibly appear in more than one path, making it a many to many relationship.

I'm finding it confusing querying for paths and get the stops back with it in one single query.

I've been trying for a while to create a function that handles this and this is how far I've come (spoiler, not that far)

```
create or replace function get_paths() returns setof paths as $$ 
  declare
    p paths[]
  begin
    select * into p from paths;
    -- not sure how to move on from here.
  end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://postgrest.org/en/latest/api.html#many-to-many-relationships

Many-to-many relationships are detected based on the join table. The join table must contain foreign keys to other two tables and they must be part of its composite key.

For the many-to-many relationship between films and actors, the join table roles would be:

```sql
create table roles(
  film_id int references films(id)
, actor_id int references actors(id)
, primary key(film_id, actor_id)
);

-- the join table can also be detected if the composite key has additional columns

create table roles(
  id int generated always as identity,
, film_id int references films(id)
, actor_id int references actors(id)
, primary key(id, film_id, actor_id)
);
```

Then you can do

```js
await supabase.from('actors').select('first_name,last_name,films(title)')
```